# zone.js@0.7.4:405 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'visitExpression' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ;

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have the following error:

```
zone.js@0.7.4:405 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'visitExpression' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'visitExpression' of undefined
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial, and at the end I even copied and pasted the full .TS files from their originaL.
Tutorial:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Full originalsource files:
https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview

However I still have the same error:

It looks like the error might be in the routing module according to other people having similar issues, but I cant find any syntax error here

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: try reproduce it with the plunker

Comment: Did you find any solution?